# Nicer one-liner for exiting bash script with error message

Tags: bash

I'd like to achieve the test with a cleaner, less ugly one-liner:

```
#!/bin/bash
test -d "$1" || (echo "Argument 1: '$1' is not a directory" 1>&2 ; exit 1) || exit 1

# ... script continues if $1 is directory...
```

Basically I am after something which does not duplicate the `exit`, and preferably does not spawn a sub-shell (and as a result should also look less ugly), but still fits in one line.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Without a subshell and without duplicating `exit`:

```
test -d "$1" || { echo "Argument 1: '$1' is not a directory" 1>&2 ; exit 1; }
```

You may also want to refer to [Grouping Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping):

> `{}`
>
> ```
> { list; }
> ```
>
> Placing a list of commands between curly braces causes the list to be executed in the current shell context. No subshell is created. The
>   semicolon (or newline) following list is required.

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know curly braces could do that. I'm very glad I asked this question, thank you :)

Comment: you could also reduce the test to `[ -d "$1" ]`

Comment: @gentoomaniac Moreover, if you feel that you have a better solution please post an answer.  Be assured that you'll earn an upvote from me in case you have a good alternative.

Comment: @gentoomaniac I prefer `test` when used alone, I feel it's clearer and more consistent with similar use of other commands (like `grep -q`). But AFAIK this is purely a matter of style, there's no technical difference.